# I try to reset my Skype password and I get redirected to their big blog page

Tags: skype-for-web, passwords

Anyone else has that problem? I try `https://login.skype.com/account/password-reset-request` and I get redirected to `http://blogs.skype.com/en/`.

Comment: Works fine here http://i.imgur.com/YEa8h.png

Comment: Also, http://heartbeat.skype.com/ claims all is fine. (Well, it actually is not, but Skype might not know about that.)

Answer (score 5):

Skype had some major problems. In some regions you are still being redirected to http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/StatusUpdate/ which itself redirects to the blog.

The same issue when testing [with Web-Sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.skype.com%2Faccount%2Fpassword-reset-request):

```
Connect to 78.141.177.141 on port 443 ... ok

GET /account/password-reset-request HTTP/1.1
Host: login.skype.com
Connection: close
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/
```

Yielding:

```
Status: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 26 Dec 2010 10:11:25 GMT 
[...]
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate,
    post-check=0, pre-check=0   
Pragma: no-cache    
[...]
Location: http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/StatusUpdate/
```

I guess you either need to wait, or contact Skype support. Without faking your whereabouts there's not a lot you can do about it on your own computer.